# Extracting a JSON substring with POSIX.2 regex

Tags: json, regex, posix

I need to extract a field value from a JSON string using POSIX.2 extended regular expressions (`man 7 regex` on Linux): eg. from `{"field":"value"}`

I'm used to working with Perl-style regex when a simple `/"field":"(.*)"/` would do the trick, but the POSIX regex don't seem to have a notion to express capture groups.

Is there a trick to craft a POSIX pattern that will match exactly the JSON value ?

Comment: Perhaps, `"field":"([^"]*)"` will work if there are no `"` inside the value.

Comment: Parsing JSON with a regexp is very error-prone. Why not just use a JSON parser library?

Comment: @Wiktor: That would still match the "field" part. I strictly need the value.

Comment: You will have in Group 1 or not? What is your real environment?

Comment: There are no anchors in the regexp you showed. Are you talking about the parentheses used for the capture group?

Comment: @Barmar: Thats right, I mean capture groups. This is inside a legacy system where I don't get to pick additional libraries. Thus the old POSIX.2 syntax.

Comment: The capture group is the problem. My regex is valid, but matches too much.

Comment: Matches too much? You used `"field":"([^"]*)"` and it works as appropriate? Or did you have to escape the parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In POSIX "basic" regular expressions, capture groups are expressed with `\(...\)`, so what you want is:

```
"field":"\([^"]*\)"
```

Note that you have to use `[^"]*` to prevent the pattern from matching across multiple strings (POSIX regular expressions don't have non-greedy quantifiers).

In "extended" regular expressions, you don't need the backslashes. But you still need to use `[^"]` instead of `.` to keep from matching too much.

Comment: The `\(...\)` is BRE, not ERE syntax. No idea if it really helps.